# Is there any way to debug a certain data structure?

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, xcode7

As my iPhone application gets increasingly more complicated, I find it more and more annoying to trace certain data structures that get passed throughout my project to various files. Just recently I noticed that I was setting my array to nil in some part of the code when I should have been removing all objects. This caused me to add objects to a nil array.

Is there any way to take a look at a certain memory location and just have a debugger catch any modifications to the data structure? I know there's an option in Xcode to catch the point of an error occurring whilst debugging, so I'm wondering if there is another option, or way, or suggested method to catch the modifications to a specific structure (NSArray, NSDictionary, etc...)

Comment: You can set a watch on a particular variable. A break will occur if that variable is changed.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Can you point me towards how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set a breakpoint in a place where the array you want to watch is in scope: either as a member variable, or as a local variable.
2. Run your app until it stops at the breakpoint.
3. Make sure the two debugging windows at the bottom of xCode are open. The one on the left will show you a list of variables.
4. Find the one you want to monitor, select it and option click. You should see a drop-down menu.
5. Select "Watch ....."
6. Turn off the breakpoint, and run your app.

Your app will break when the variable is changed.

Answer (score 0):

KVO is one approach to get notified when object value is modified. But would need additional code and not sure if it suites your case.